# Screen Recording in Quick Time 7 not available

Tags: quicktime

Just bought a new MacBook Pro 15" Retina display laptop with Maverick. Was needing to record an app on my screen. Went to Quick Time 7 and Quick Time 7 Player opened up. Registration for Pro was already set. How do you enable Screen Recording in Quick Time 7?

Comment: Quick Time 7 Player was in the Applications folder. After placing Quick Time 7 Player in the trash the Quick Time X was now available in the Applications folder. This is the first time i have ever ran across this as a solution

Answer (score 1):

This is not a QuickTime 7 feature but a QuickTime X feature  !